# bluemix VM running Grafana and IBM Id authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, single-sign-on, ibm-cloud, grafana

I am researching the following.

I have setup a VM on bluemix and installed grafana (grafana.org).
This is a web application for building visual dashboards.

The VM is accessible on the public cloud as it has a public IP. I noticed it also has a private IP. When I hit the public url for grafana it first presents a logon dialog. It defaults to using local file based user/passwords. Grafana supports LDAP authentication.

I want to authenticate users before they can use grafana using an existing IBM id.
Secondly, if the user has already logged with that id then invoking grafana allows the user to continue without prompting for logon. I suppose this is SSO.
Thirdly, I want to restrict the set of IBM ids who can access the application.

The first is what I want to achieve, the second and third are optional at this time.

I know very little about LDAP, SSO, authentication standards/systems so need some pointers here.  The general question is how to integrate IBM ID service into a bluemix-hosted or not application.
    What would some of the network/application prerequisites be? Can it be done with just LDAP?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to refer to the IBM internal wiki for SSO integration